# Max & Min 1 Function in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++17

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int ma_mi(int a[],int n)
{
    int i, max = a[0], min = a[0]; // problem with max and min
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin>>*(a+i);
        if (*(a+i)>max) *(a+i)=max;
        if (*(a+i)<min) *(a+i)=min;
    }
    cout<<"max is"<<' '<<max<<' '<<"min is"<<' '<<min;
}
int main()
{
    int i, n, a[n];
    cin>> n;
    ma_mi(a,n);
}
```

END of Source Code

Input

```
6
-80 800 -8000 -800 80 8000
```

Output

```
max is 4253776 min is 4253776
```

Comment: `int i, n, a[n];` is Undefined Behaviour.  As `a` is created before `n` is initialised.

Comment: `*(a+i)=max` which one do you want to modify?

Comment: Your function is supposed to return an `int`, but it does not return anything. This is also UB.

Comment: You don’t need an array, and you’re assigning “backwards”.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Ok i'm newbie and i'm in university this si the first time iever had try c++/c so this is a mix up but u know i try it i'm so thank u with every comments.

Answer (score 3):

- You are using `n` (in `int i,n,a[n];` and `a[0]` before they are initialized.
- `*(a+i)=max;` and `*(a+i)=min;` should be `max=*(a+i);` and `min=*(a+i);` to update `max` and `min`.
- Variable-length array is not in the standard C++.

```
# include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int ma_mi(int a[],int n)
{
    int i,max,min; // problem with max and min
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>*(a+i);
        if(i==0)
        {
            max = min = a[0];
        }
        else
        {
            if (*(a+i)>max) max=*(a+i);
            if (*(a+i)<min) min=*(a+i);
        }
    }
    cout<<"max is"<<' '<<max<<' '<<"min is"<<' '<<min;
}
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    cin>>n;
    int* a = new int[n];
    ma_mi(a,n);
    delete[] a;
}
```

Comment: Also need to flip `*(a+i)=max` -> `max = *(a+i)`.  And for clarity, change the `*(a+i)`s to `a[i]`s.

Comment: `std::vector` could avoid the ugly allocation here, but that may be a whole other can of worms.

Comment: I would also split collecting input, and computing min/max.

Comment: actually my teacher doesn't want me 2 use a vector he want me 2 use a simple array from c or pointer mashup with something from c++